# how to add button and action against that button in openerp7

Tags: xml, workflow, odoo

I am new in Openerp 7, i installed purchase requisition module, in openerp 7 there is not approval method in purchase requisition i add custom button through view

```
        <header>
```

```
            <button name="tender_in_progress" states="draft" string="Send to Suppliers" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
           <button name="tender_in_progress" states="draft" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
            <button name="tender_reset" states="done,cancel" string="Reset to Draft" type="object"/>
            <button name="tender_done" states="in_progress" string="Purchase Done" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
            <button name="tender_cancel" states="draft,in_progress" string="Cancel Requisition" type="object"/>
            <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,in_progress,done" statusbar_colors="{&quot;in_progress&quot;:&quot;blue&quot;}"/>
        </head
```

and change the flow or purchase-basic flow
draft->approve->sent

button is displaying but i don't know how it will perform action that status of purchase requisition change from new to approved after click Approve button.
please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

Work flow will not only work on adding such buttons but also You need to create workflow transition.

Work flow is principally technical processes defined in a vertical way on the lifecycle of a complete object.

FYI: You can try & make on basis of "account_invoice_workflow.xml".

Comment: if i do not change workflow then is it possible i just add a button and that can perform an action?